# Updating an activities field from within a static DateDialogFragment in Android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am trying to implement an `EditText` field that when clicked will display a date picker. From what I had read, a `DateDialogFragment` was recommended as a modern solution.

I've stripped out irrelevent code from the activity for simplicity:

```
public class EditStepCountEntryActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    private EditText mChangeDateField;
    private static DateTimeFormatter dateFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.LONG);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit_step_count_entry);

        initViews();
    }

    private void initViews()
    {
        mChangeDateField = findViewById(R.id.changeDateField);
        mChangeDateField.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
        mChangeDateField.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                onChangeDateButtonClicked();
            }
        });
    }

    public void onChangeDateButtonClicked()
    {
        DateDialogFragment datePicker = new DateDialogFragment();
        datePicker.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "showDate");
    }

    public class DateDialogFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener
    {
        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(mStepCountDate.getText(), dateFormat);
            int year = date.getYear();
            int month = date.getMonthValue();
            int day = date.getDayOfMonth();

            return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
        }

        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth)
        {
            showSetDate(LocalDate.of(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth));
        }
    }

    public void showSetDate(LocalDate date)
    {
        String dateText = date.format(dateFormat);
        mStepCountDate.setText(dateText);
    }
}
```

When I click the `EditText` I get the following error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment
>   com.example.android.keepfitapp.EditStepCountEntryActivity.DateDialogFragment
>   must be a public static class to be  properly recreated from instance
>   state.
>           at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction.doAddOp(FragmentTransaction.java:249)
>           at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.doAddOp(BackStackRecord.java:180)
>           at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction.add(FragmentTransaction.java:171)
>           at androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment.show(DialogFragment.java:174)
>           at com.example.android.keepfitapp.EditStepCountEntryActivity.onChangeDateButtonClicked(EditStepCountEntryActivity.java:187)

The error states that the `Fragment` must be static, however if the `Fragment` is static I would no longer have access to the `Activity` `EditText`.

I could potentially pass the date to the `Fragment` in a bundle but how can I get the new date entered back into the `Activity`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi i had the same problem. This is how i solve it :

**Step 1** make your activity implement DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener(and remove it from DialogFragment).

**Step 2**, Replace code from **onCreateDialog** to:

```
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    // Activity needs to implement this interface
    DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener listener = (DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener) getActivity();
    DatePickerDialog q = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), listener, year, month, day);
    return q;
```

**Step 3** , Override onDateSet method in your **activity**(and remove it from DialogFragment) and update your text field when date is set.

Hope it answer your question :)

---

A **Full** working example: (To make it easy to understand :) ) :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {
TextView mChangeDateField;
@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mChangeDateField = findViewById(R.id.changeDateField);

}

public void setDateText(View view){
    ClientChooseDateFragment newFragment =
            new ClientChooseDateFragment();
    newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),
            "datePicker");

}

@Override
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
    mChangeDateField.setText("-- " + year + "--- Month" +month);
}


public static class  ClientChooseDateFragment extends DialogFragment {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current time as the default values for the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        // Activity needs to implement this interface
        DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener listener = (DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener) getActivity();
        DatePickerDialog q = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), listener, year, month, day);

        return q;
    }
}}
```